# Jquery hide parent div if has no sliding div

Tags: jquery

Here is html code:

```
<div class="content bb page_3">
<div class="c_slide"></div>
</div>
<div class="links" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Need hide functions to links class, if in content div has one c_slide divs.

```
<div class="content bb page_3">
<div class="c_slide"></div>
<div class="c_slide"></div>
<div class="c_slide"></div>
</div>
<div class="links"></div>
```

Comment: I have slider navigation links in links class like read more, or next links. If i have only one slide, i need to hide this navigation.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
if($('div.content').children('div.c_slide').length == 1){
    $('div.links').hide();
}else{
    $('div.links').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( ($('div.content > div.cslide').size()) > 1 ) {
  $('div.links').hide();
}else {
  $('div.links').show();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
if ( $('.content').children("div.c_slide").length == 1) {
  $("div.links").hide();
}
```